# Retriving collection of words from mysql extract it as single word and show

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get each word one by one from the following situation.

my query result is like

```
feeder_group      feeder_name

 mobile           Fitbit,Social Badge,Rf Id

 social           facebook,twitter
```

so when i do `echo $_row[feeder_group]` or `echo $_row[feeder_name]` am getting result like 
mobile,social or  Fitbit,Social Badge,Rf Id.I want to dispaly this words like
facbook
twitter.
Is there anyway to acheive this.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string          = 'facebook,twitter';

$explodedString  = explode(',', $string);
$implodedString  = implode(' ', $explodedString);

echo $implodedString;
```

result:

```
facebook twitter
```

Answer (score 0):

[str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) replace all instances of ',' in the string with ' ', which should do what you request.

```
   $feeder_name = str_replace(',',' ',$_row['feeder_name']);
```

You could also re-assing to `$_row['feeder_name']` if you wanted to.